# How to get data from Laravel relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 2 models: publictxt and Pulicetxtrecive

publictxt model:

```
class Publictxt extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=['sender','reciver','description','useridseen'];

    public function Publictxtrecives()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Pulicetxtrecive::class,'publictxt_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Pulicetxtrecive model:

```
protected $fillable=['publictxt_id','user_id','seen'];

public function publictxts()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Publictxt::class);
}
```

I want to get the values ​​from the Publictxt that are available in the Pulicetxtrecive.
When a record is stored in the Publictxt, users are registered in the Pulicetxtrecive after viewing.

```
$pulictxtcount=Publictxt::where('reciver',Auth::user()->shift)->orwhere('reciver',1)->with('Publictxtrecives')->whereHas('Publictxtrecives',function($q){$q->where('seen', '=', 0);})->count();
```

this code doesn't work.

Comment: How is Publictxt and User connected? Show user relationship for full solution

Comment: The manager sends a letter and specifies who it should reach. After sending the letter, every user who opens the letter is registered in the Pulicetxtrecive table. I want to retrieve the letters that are not saved in the Pulicetxtrecive , or in other words, they have not seen the letter.  Publictxt and User dont have relation.

Comment: Inside your `Pulicetxtrecive` you gave a relationship with the `user` model. Show that relationship

Comment: @alirezasheibani so if im a user, and i open my account, i can see the letter, and i can open it. If i open it, it will mark it as received by me right?

Comment: yes , this code is : $recive=new Pulicetxtrecive;
        $recive->user_id=auth()->user()->id;
        $recive->seen=1;
        $publictxt->Publictxtrecives()->save($recive);
        return view('report.publictxtdetail',compact('publictxt'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem:

$pulictxtcount = Publictxt::where(function($q){$q->where('reciver',Auth::user()->shift)->orwhere('reciver',1);})->whereDoesntHave('Publictxtrecives', function($q){$q->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
})->count();

Comment: Please apply proper formatting to your code (as in the question).

Answer (score 1):

There are some conflicts in your database structure.

You said when a user sees a letter the `Publictxtrecives` will be created.
That means if a `Publictxt` has a `Publictxtrecives` that definitely has been seen .
But there is a `seen` column in `Publictxtrecives` table.
You should pick one.
But anyway as this structure:

```
$pulictxtcount=Publictxt::where(
 function($query){
  $query->where('reciver',Auth::user()
  ->shift)->orwhere('reciver',1);
})
->Where(function($query)
  {
$query->whereHas('Publictxtrecives',
  function($q){$q->where('seen',1);
               }
)->orWhereDoesntHave('Publictxtrecives');
})
->with('Publictxtrecives');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this code has a syntax problem

Comment: Sorry I posted in the mobile. I updated it. But seriously reccomend you to redesign the database structure

Answer (score 0):

```
$pulictxtcount = Publictxt::with([
        'Publictxtrecives' => function($query){
            $query->where('seen', 0);
        }
        ])
        ->where('reciver', Auth::user()->shift)
        ->orwhere('reciver', 1)
        ->get();
```